# How do you leave testing automation and switch to something like development?

Tags: career-switch, new-hires

I'm about to graduate college in a couple months and I have a job offer lined up for once I graduate. The job was from my summer internship where I did testing automation. My concern is that in my very first internship I did test automation alongside actual development work, but now my resume of professional work is 2/3 test automation.

I'm worried that I will be typecast as the test automation employee and I find it extremely boring. I'm also thinking that in the job that I will be joining in a couple months I'm going to be doing test automation since that was my intern role.

So based on my experience and where I am headed as a new hire, how would I leave this career path without it starting and move to something more interesting such as big data, ML or just any development?

I should add, I have personal projects for big data and ML on my resume and on my github.

Comment: Do you program as part of automating tests?  If yes, pursue that!

Answer (score 11):

> but now my resume of professional work is 2/3 test automation.

Just apply for the jobs you want. If you don't want to do test automation, don't apply for those jobs.

Your resume of professional work is a summer internship. What you did there makes a difference, but not much. A big part of an internship is to prove you can actually get out of bed in the morning and work without annoying your colleagues too much.

Comment: _"A big part of an internship is to prove you can actually get out of bed in the morning and work without annoying your colleagues too much"_  - brilliant analysis.. ;)